# Incorrect syntax near 'TO'. Expecting DOUBLECOLON

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, encryption, encryption-asymmetric, sql-grant

I'm trying to grant access to to use an asymmetric key a database user.

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON ASYMMETRIC KEY ak TO dbuser
```

SSMS highlights `TO` with the following error

```
Incorrect syntax near 'TO'. Expecting DOUBLECOLON.
```

What does this mean? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you read [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187991.aspx)?

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON ASYMMETRIC KEY :: ak TO dbuser
```

You need the `::` for most non-standard-SQL objects in some commands, especially GRANT